# unable to cast object of type system.string to type system.io.fileinfo

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, type-conversion

Hello I'm trying to use the path inside my listbox but it came out an error

```
Dim items As New ListBox

'Getting the path of the selected file on opendialog'
For Each filename As String In OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
    items.Items.Add(filename)
Next

For Each sourcepath As FileInfo In items.Items()
    sourcepath.CopyTo(path)
Next
```

Comment: You're a kamikaze programmer. Set the [strict compiler option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) to **on* ASAP.

Comment: do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Sure, read the answer posted by [Guffa](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31099413/1842065).

Comment: there's a syntax error on "new" line, cannot get it to work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to read this *carefully*: [Ask].  *but it came out an error* is not very useful

Comment: i already post the error message at the title, what more do you want me to explain.

Answer (score 3):

You have put strings in the list box, so when you loop the items you will get strings back. If you want `FileInfo` objects you have to create them from the strings:

```
For Each sourcepath As String In items.Items
    Dim fileInfo = New FileInfo(sourcepath).CopyTo(path)
Next
```

Comment: turns out syntax error on this  one. :( error on the "new"

Comment: @Teeed.Com I've updated the answer. You need to add `Dim fileInfo = ` before the `New` keyword.